# IntelliJ Kotlin build does nothing

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have seen the following issue repeatedly while building multiple Kotlin projects using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate `Build #IU-222.3739.54` (August 2022) and Kotlin plugin `222-1.7.10-release-334-IJ3739.54`:

After making a change to existing sources and attempting to run a functional test I get an error such as:

```
Kotlin: Cannot find a parameter with this name: plan_type
```

The change I just made was adding the said enumeration to an existing enum class. Checking the logs I see mention of the alleged compilation error that gets displayed in the IDE:

```
2022-09-06 18:03:51,521 [1573161]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appEditorSettings took 15 ms, FileTypeManager took 14 ms
2022-09-06 18:04:14,831 [1596471]   INFO - #c.i.c.i.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS)
2022-09-06 18:04:15,975 [1597615]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile /Users/lexluthor/Workspaces/billing-service
2022-09-06 18:04:15,994 [1597634]   INFO - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexStorage - KCRI storage is closed
2022-09-06 18:04:16,013 [1597653]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is closed
2022-09-06 18:05:33,532 [1675172]   INFO - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexStorage - KCRI storage is opened: took 50 ms for 1 storages (filling map: 47 ms, flush to storage: 3 ms)
2022-09-06 18:05:33,551 [1675191]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened
2022-09-06 18:05:33,886 [1675526]   INFO - #c.i.c.i.CompilerUtil -      COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 1; warnings: 0 took 79046 ms: 1 min 19sec
2022-09-06 18:05:34,264 [1675904]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Users/lexluthor/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/222.3739.54/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
2022-09-06 18:05:46,991 [1688631]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=billing-service, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=/Users/lexluthor/Workspaces/billing-service)RunManager took 18 ms
```

> COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 1

There doesn't appear to be any mention of the said error anywhere else in the log output. Here's some additional observations I have made:

- The issue only occurs when building a Kotlin project using Gradle and the language version is `1.7.0` or `1.7.10`. The issue does not occur if I set the language version to either `1.6.21` or `1.7.20-Beta`.
- The issue only occurs when using the *IntelliJ IDEA* builder under *Gradle Settings*: `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Gradle Projects | Build and run | Build and run using`. Switching to the *Gradle* builder in the aforementioned settings allows me to build the project *without any errors*. Subsequently switching back to the *IntelliJ IDEA* builder after a successful *Gradle* build appears to fix the issue in the IDE.
- The issue cannot be easily reproduced on a trivial project. I have not been able to reproduce the issue using a demo project generated using [Spring Initilzr](https://start.spring.io/) but I experience this issue frequently while making trivial changes to existing, medium-size, Kotlin projects *and* the previous two conditions are met.

I have searched the issue in [JetBrains YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KTIJ) without success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer to this question from JetBrains technical support that I thought of sharing here for the benefit of anyone else who has come across this issue:

> From my checking, your issue looks the same as the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53168/
> There is a bug in the incremental compilation which is fixed in the 1.7.20-Beta.
>
> You could use the 1.7.20-Beta for it currently or use other workarounds (like Gradle builder)